# The c program results in output 2 why?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 2;
    int z = ~x & y;
    printf("%d\n", z);
}
```

can any body tell the how the operation is being take place with respect to how the variables are saved in the memory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me make this shorter using just 8 bits:

```
x         0   00000000
y         2   00000010
~x       -1   11111111
~x & y    2   00000010
```

Bitwise-complement `~` will complement (invert value) of each bit of its operand (`1` becomes `0` and `0` becomes `1`). Bitwise-AND `&` will set a bit to `1` if it's `1` in both its operands:

```
lhs    rhs    lhs AND rhs
 0      0          0   
 0      1          0   
 1      0          0   
 1      1          1
```

Then, for example, `011b & 001b` will result in `001b` (because only LSB is `1` in both operands). In your case negating `x` (which is `0`) you have 32 bits set to `1` so result will depend entirely by `y` (because `1 AND RHS = RHS`, see last two lines in the truth table).

**Important:** Please note that your code isn't portable, according to ANSI C bitwise-AND behavior for signed integers is implementation defined (so what works in your implementation may be broken on another platform/compiler or with another compiler version).

Answer (score 4):

I'll use binairy to explain why

```
int x = 0;      //x = 0000
int y = 2;      //y = 0010
int z = ~x & y;
```

Now, `~x` is `x` inverse so `1111`
The `&` does a bitwize and (`&&` does logical and) so:

```
~x & y
1111 & 0010
0010
```

And `0010` is 2

*Note:* I'm using 4 bit's but in fact depending on implementation this could be 32 bit (or 16). The idea remains the same

Comment: An `int` is, nowadays, typically 32 bits wide. But: funny enough, the number of bits is entirely *inconsequential* -- this will work with any integer type.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding the operator `~` is the key, and note that `~` operator is not the same as the `NOT` operator.

x = 0

~x = 0xFFFFFFFF

y = 0x00000002;

z = 0xFFFFFFFF & 0x00000002;

z = 0x2;

**The Bitwise Complement**

The bitwise complement operator, the tilde, ~, flips every bit. A useful way to remember this is that the tilde is sometimes called a twiddle, and the bitwise complement twiddles every bit: if you have a 1, it's a 0, and if you have a 0, it's a 1.

To know more about bitwise operators visit this [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of the example I'd use unsigned integers so we will calculate the binary way more easily.

If integer `x` is 0 than its value is `00000000000000000000000000000000` (32 bits - each one is 0).

Now, when you say `~x` you mean complement `x` which flips all of the bits - each bit that was on would be now off and each bit that was off would be on. Means X would be now `11111111111111111111111111111111` (32 bits - each one is 1).

It is the maximum value an unsigned integer can contain. When you use bitwise AND on all of the bits of a number which is ONLY ones, the result would be the second number.
Examples:

```
1 & 0 is 0.
11 & 01 is 01.
111 & 001 is 001
111111111111 & 00100101 is 00100101
```

And so on.

Comment: @mps just one more clarification, exactly how does the following two numbers will be saved in machine
    unsigned int k = -4;
    int k = -4;